# ¿Como pasar una relación binaria al modelo relacional con atributo en la relación?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

tengo una duda del pasaje de modelo entidad relación a modelo relacional .

Cuando tengo una relación binaria de n a 1 y también un atributo de relación (sea descriptivo o clave) ¿Se pierde en el modelo relacional?

Por ejemplo si tengo la siguiente relación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo relacional seria así:

```
Estudiante(lu)
Pk lu


Materia (codigo, lu , nota)
Pk codigo , 
Fk lu->Estudiante.lu
```

¿El atributo nota iría del lado de la N? ¿O no se pone el atributo, directamente se pierde eso en el modelo relacional? 
¿Y que pasa si tengo lo mismo en una relacion de 1 a 1?

Comment: Vi un intento de aclarar la pregunta editándola, pero debería ser el mismo usuario el que use menos siglas (que no son estándar) y nos diga de qué va la pregunta :)

Comment: ¡Buenas @Alfabravo! En el entorno académico (FP, etc..) si se suele usar bastante ese tipo de siglas. Por eso pensé en editarlas. Igualmente lo aclaro en este comentario: **MR** Modelo Relacional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Buenas!

Para la casuistica 1:N se suele arrastrar, como normal general, hacia la N. Por tanto, las claves foráneas y los atributos de la relación se arrastrarán hacia la N.

Existen otras casuisticas en 1:N, pero son más específicas.

En la casuistica 1:1 existen más opciones[. En este documento](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.codecompiling.net/files/slides/BD_clase_07_ERE_relacional.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiw2pOejpPnAhWr0eAKHcZaBt0QFjADegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3ehlDa5UNwY2ZbuRmM_tQx&cshid=1579555408684) puedes encontrar más información al respecto.

Además ahí te aclara la sintaxis correcta para el modelo relacional.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias :D